# Maximum value of M digits out of N digits

Tags: c++

I am trying to code a program that can do something like this:

```
in:
 5 4
 1 9 9 9 0

out:
9990
```

and i have a problem. It doesnt work on any set of numbers. For example it works for the one above, but it doesnt work for this one:

```
in:
15 9
2 9 3 6 5 8 8 8 8 7 2 2 8 1 4


out: 988887814
```

2 **9** 3 6 5 **8** **8** **8** **8** **7** 2 2 **8** **1** **4**

I did this with a vector approach and it works for any set of numbers, but i'm trying to do it a stack for a better complexity.

EDIT ---- MODIFIED FOR STD::STACK
Code for method using stack:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stack>
using namespace std;

ifstream in("trompeta.in");
ofstream out("trompeta.out");

void reverseStack(stack<char> st) {
    if(!st.empty())
    {
        char x = st.top();
        st.pop();
        reverseStack(st);
        out<<x;
    }
    return;
}
int main()
{
    int n,m,count=1;
    stack <char> st;
    char x;
    in>>n>>m;
    in>>x;
    st.push(x);

     for(int i=1; i<n; i++)
        {
            in>>x;
            if(st.top()<x && count+n-i-1>=m)
            {
              st.pop();
              st.push(x);
            }
            else
            {
                st.push(x);
                count++;
                if (count>m-1) break;
            }
        };

    reverseStack(st);
}
```

Code for method using vectors:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
ifstream in ( "trompeta.in" );
ofstream out ( "trompeta.out" );
int main ()
{
    int i = 0, N, M, max, j, p = 0, var;
    in >> N >> M;
    char* v = new char[N];
    char* a = new char[M];
    in >> v;
    var = M;
    max = v[0];
    for ( i = 0; i < M; i++ )
    {
        for ( j = p ; j < N-var+1; j++ )
        {
            if ( v[j] > max  )
            {
                max = v[j];
                p = j;
            }
        }
        var--;
        a[i] = max;
        max = v[p+1];
        p = p+1;
    }
    for ( i = 0; i < M; i++ )
        out << a[i]-'0';
}
```

Can any1 help me to get the STACK code working?

Comment: Huh? What are you even trying to do? Your title doesn't correspond with your example or your code.

Comment: If you want to use a stack why not use `std::stack`?  It gets rid of any chance that your stack implementation is flawed.

Comment: The output of your first example should be `9991` not `9990` according to your own description.

Comment: @Smac89 Is my first time posting here and i didnt know how to describe it.

Comment: Why can't you just sort the N digits and pick the first M digits?

Comment: @Rahn it need to be done without changing the order of the initial numbers. So the correct answer is 9990.

Comment: wait what? if the ordering is important, shouldn't it then be `1999` ?

Comment: @vu1p3n0x the order should stay unchange but i can jump over numbers to get the maximum value out of M digits.

Comment: Basically from the IN numbers, i have to select a sequence of maximum M digits without changing the order of the initial sequence

Comment: oh, because `9990` is larger than `1999`. You're evaluating the sequence of N numbers as digits of a number, right?

Comment: @NathanOliver I am new to C++ and previous i wrote that code for implementing a stack and tought would be a good idea to use that. I dont think that is the problem though, since it works for some datas

Comment: @vu1p3n0x thats right

Comment: @NathanOliver i've changed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now your code has quite a few issues, but rather than focusing on those lets answer the question. Let's say that your code has been corrected to give us:

- `const size_t M` where `M` is the number of digits expected in our output
- `const vector<int> v` which is the input set of numbers of size `N`

You just always want to pick the highest value most significant number remaining. So we'll keep an `end` iterator to prevent us from picking a digit that wouldn't leave us with enough digits to finish the number, and use [`max_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) to select:

```
const int pow10[] = { 1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000, 10000000, 100000000, 1000000000 };
auto maximum = 0;
auto end = prev(cend(v), M - 1);
auto it = max_element(cbegin(v), end);

for (auto i = M - 1; i > 0; --i) {
    maximum += *it * pow10[i];
    advance(end, 1);
    it = max_element(next(it), end);
}
maximum += *it;
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](http://ideone.com/jljbvE)

This code depends upon `M` being greater than 0 and less than `N` and less than `log10(numeric_limits<int>::max())`

**EDIT: Sad to say this solves the consecutive digits problem, after edits the question wants subsequent digits, but not necessarily consecutive**

<strike>So the little known `numeric` library provides [`inner_product`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/inner_product) which seems like just the tool for this job. Now your code has quite a few issues, but rather than focusing on those lets answer the question. Let's say that your code has been corrected to give us:</strike>

- `vector<int> foo(M)` where `M` is the number of digits expected in our output
- `const vector<int> v` which is the input set of numbers of size `N`

We'll use `foo` in the `inner_product`, initializing it with decreasing powers of 10:

```
generate(begin(foo), end(foo), [i=int{1}]() mutable {
    auto result = i;
    i *= 10;
    return result; });
```

We can then use this in a loop:

```
auto maximum = 0;

for (auto it = prev(rend(v), size(foo) + 1); it != rbegin(v); advance(it, -1)) {
    maximum = max<int>(inner_product(cbegin(foo), cend(foo), it, 0), maximum);
}
maximum = max<int>(inner_product(cbegin(foo), cend(foo), rbegin(v), 0), maximum);
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](http://ideone.com/LFt6C6)

To use `it`'s initialization requires that your initial `M` was smaller than `N`, so you may want to `assert` that or something.

Comment: This is computing every answer and then iterating through them to find the max, right?

Comment: the problem is, this algorithm is searching the maximum consecutive sequence, but the sequence in the solution doesn't have to be consecutive.

Comment: @KennyOstrom Unfortunately this was calculating the value of each number made of `M` *consecutive* digits. I've corrected it where it's finding the best possible digit for each of the *subsequent* `M` digits.

Comment: @IonuțZamfir Good catch, I didn't understand that until the question was edited. I have edited.

Comment: @JonathanMee can you explain what "auto" means? I am not familiarized with this declaration. I've never seen it b4.

Comment: @JonathanMee although this seem to be a correct abordation, i can't understand anything except the declarations of M,vector and pow. Can you translate for a gcc5.1 user?

Comment: @IonuțZamfir So [`auto`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) is a C++11 concept. Basically you can think of it as inline templating. It's going to look at the right hand side of the constructor and take on the type of the argument provided. So the `0` in `auto minimum = 0` is an `int` meaning that `minimum` is just an `int`. Likewise `prev` and `max_element` return the type of their first argument so, a const iterator. For more info on `auto`, you can check out [Herb Sutter's explanation](https://herbsutter.com/2013/08/12/gotw-94-solution-aaa-style-almost-always-auto/).

Comment: @IonuțZamfir If the explanation in the answer is unclear or you have questions about how the algorithm works let's sort them out here. On of the best tools to understanding is the [Live Example](http://ideone.com/jljbvE) I've given, play around with that! If you have questions about how some of the C++ functionality works, that should probably be a new question, but if you link it to me here I'll come try to answer!

Answer (score 1):

Using the fact that the most significant digit completely trumps all other digets except in place of a tie, I would look at the first (N-M+1) digits, find the largest single digit in that range.

If it occurs once, the first digit is locked in. Discard the digits which occur prior to that position, and you repeat for "maximum value of M-1 numbers of out N-position" to find the remaining digits of the answer. (or N-position-1, if position is zero based)

If it occurs multiple times, then recursively find "maximum value of M-1 numbers out of N-position" for each, then select the largest single result from these. There can be at most N such matches.

I forgot to mention, if N==M, you are also done.

proof of recursion:
Computing the value of the sub-match will always select M-1 digits. When M is 1, you only need to select the largest of a few positions, and have no more recursion. This is true for both cases.  Also the "select from" steps always contain no more than N choices, because they are always based on selecting one most significant digit.

------------------ how you might do it with a stack ----------------

An actual implementation using a stack would be based on an object which contains the entire state of the problem, at each step, like so:

```
struct data { // require: n == digits.size()
    int n, m;
    std::string digits;
    bool operator<(const data &rhs){ return digits < rhs.digits; }
};
```

The point of this is not just to store the original problem, but to have a way to represent any subproblem, which you can push and pop on a stack. The stack itself is not really important, here, because it is used to pick the one best result within a specific layer.  Recursion handles most of the work.

Here is the top level function which hides the data struct:

```
std::string select_ordered_max(int n, int m, std::string digits) {
    if (n < m || (int)digits.size() != n)
        return "size wrong";
    data d{ n, m, digits };
    data answer = select_ordered_max(d);
    return answer.digits;
}
```

and a rough pseudocode of the recursive workhorse

```
data select_ordered_max(data original){
    // check trivial return conditions
    // determine char most_significant
    // push all subproblems that satisfy most_significant 
        //(special case where m==1)
    // pop subproblems, remembering best
    return answer {original.m, original.m, std::string(1, most_significant) + best_submatch.digits };
```

}

String comparison works on numbers when you only compare strings of the exact same length, which is the case here.

Yes, I know having n and m is redundant with digits.size(), but I didn't want to work too hard. Including it twice simplified some recursion checks. The actual implementation only pushed a candidate to the stack if it passed the max digit check for that level of recursion.  This allowed me to get the correct 9 digit answer from 15 digits of input with only 28 candidates pushed to the stack (and them popped during max-select).

Comment: if you scroll down in the main post, somewhere on the middle is wrote "Code for method using vectors:" where i did exactly this thing. But i was hoping for an implementation using a stack.

Comment: So you just want finished code?

Comment: Not really. I just wanted an idea to make the stack method work. But everyone suggest vectors approach when i clarified that i managed to solve the problem using vectors.

Comment: done and tested on the 9-of-15 sample.  Answer updated, but I'm not posting all the code.

Comment: Ty for sharing. Marked as answer. Starting to read and apply. I will ask questions if i dont understand something.

Comment: I probably should have checked isdigit on the inputs, too.

Comment: I actually forgot to say that is specified in the problem's statement that N>M and they are digits. so i dont have to handle that code wise

Comment: Looks like I overcomplicated it. There was never any reason to check beyond the first max candidate, so no reason for a stack.

Answer (score 0):

--EDITED--

here's my suggestion with STACK based on my previous suggestion using vector

```
findMaxValueOutOfNDigits(stackInput, M, N)
{
  // stackInput = [2, 9, 3, 6, 5, 8, 8, 8, 8, 7, 2, 2, 8, 1, 4]
  // *where 4 was the first element to be inserted and 2 was the last to be inserted
  // if the sequence is inverted, you can quickly fix it by doing a "for x = 0; x < stack.length; x++ { newStack.push(stack.pop()) }"

  currentMaxValue = 0

  for i = 0; i < (M - N + 1); i++
  {
    tempValue = process(stackInput, M, N)
    stackInput.pop()
    if (tempValue > currentMaxValue)
      currentMaxValue = tempValue
  }

  return currentMaxValue
}

process(stackInput, M, N)
{
  tempValue = stackInput.pop() * 10^(N - 1)
  *howManyItemsCanILook = (M - N + 1)

  for y = (N - 2); y == 0; y++
  {
    currentHowManyItemsCanILook = *howManyItemsCanILook

    tempValue = tempValue + getValue(stackInput, *howManyItemsCanILook) * 10^(y)

    *howManyItemsCanILook = *howManyItemsCanILook - 1

    for x = 0; x < (currentHowManyItemsCanILook - *howManyItemsCanILook); x++
    {
      stackInput.pop()
    }
  }

  return tempValue
}

getValue(stackInput, *howManyItemsCanILook)
{
  currentMaxValue = stackInput.pop()
  if (currentMaxValue == 9)
    return 9
  else
  {
    goUntil = *howManyItemsCanILook

    for i = 0; i < goUntil; i++
    {
      *howManyItemsCanILook = *howManyItemsCanILook - 1
      tempValue = stackInput.pop()
      if (currentMaxValue < tempValue)
      {
        currentMaxValue = tempValue
           if (currentMaxValue == 9)
                return currentMaxValue
      }
    }
    return currentMaxValue
  }

}
```

note: where *howManyItemsCanILook is passed by reference

I hope this helps

Comment: you kind of misunderstood and i dont blame you because i kind of dont know how to explain this properly. I dont have to work with such large numbers. They are stored by digits.

Comment: For the second example, the answer should be 9 8 8 8 8 7 8 1 4

Comment: I'd personally use `std::string` to hold the digits and just compare them as strings. using `str.erase(str.begin())` and `str.push_back(c)` to get the next string. you don't actually need to calculate the value

Comment: @IonuțZamfir it looks like his solution would give you that answer...

Comment: @vu1p3n0x thats what i tried too, comparing digits but not as strings, as numbers and getting the solution without actually calculate the value. all these using a stack. and i kind of wanna use the stack, because this is an problem for exercising with stacks

Comment: This isn't the kind of problem to use a stack for. It'd really be more like a queue problem (pop front, push back)

Comment: @IonuțZamfir considering that the answer should be 9 8 8 8 8 7 8 1 4 for your second example, I added a modified algorithm in my post. is the new algorithm helpful ?

Comment: @awdk yes it is helpful

Comment: but i was hoping for an implementation using a STACK. Using vectors i managed to find a solution too. If you scroll in the main post, you will find "Code for method using vectors:"

Comment: @IonuțZamfir here's a new suggestion using STACK based on my previous post